# Lazy puzzler's masyu

Tags: grid-deduction, masyu

The creator of this masyu forgot to add the final stone, so the puzzle remains incomplete. Finish his job for him by placing one additional stone (either black or white) on the board so that the result is a uniquely solvable masyu.

Normal [masyu rules](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/masyu.html) apply.

> [image]

Comment: -1 for your laziness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm too lazy to add an explanation?

> [image]

Comment: Yep, this is correct!

Comment: @Jafe is this the only answer?  I love the idea for this puzzle

Comment: Yeah, there's only one solution (unless I've made a mistake, which occasionally happens). I have to say this took quite a few tries to get right :P

Answer (score 3):

There are actually 3 solutions

> [image]

Comment: Nice finding! I believe these solutions are actually correct.